# jQuery prop disable not working in Android browser

Tags: android, jquery, web-applications, disabled-input

In a desktop browser (Chrome) I can set an input field to disabled with the jQuery function:
`inputVar.prop('disabled',true)`.
This same exact code seems to do nothing in an Android browser on a GS3 phone. I've tested on Android Chrome and the default browser.

Any alternatives?
I've also tried these with no luck.

```
inputVar.attr('disabled','');
inputVar.attr('disabled','disabled');
inputVar[0].disabled = false;
```

**EDIT**
The full code

```
$("fieldset#myFieldSet > input").each(function(){
    var inputVar = $(this);// This is the jquery object of the input
    inputVar.prop('disabled',true);
});
```

Comment: Does `inputVar[0].disabled = true` work?

Comment: This works in a browser and may also work on Android, but something as simple as hiding an element with `.hide()` doesn't work right now. i've posted my full code.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, the valid syntax using attr would be `inputVar.attr('disabled','disabled')`, have you tried that?

Also, make sure your selector is working (try hiding the input or something) before you assume it's the disabling that is the issue.

Comment: hmm. I think you're on to something. Something simple as `inputVar.hide()` doesn't work anywhere.

Comment: Try the selector $("fieldset#myFieldSet input") instead